# How do I plot a stacked bar chart, given percentages?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I plot a stacked bar chart using ggplot2?

Given the below data, I want year on the x-axis, and the y-axis to be treated as stacked, with late_percent as the proportion.

I want the y-axis filled with 2 colors based on the percentage given: 0.16 means 16% one color and 84% another color; apply this the same all the way across for every year.

This is my dataframe:

```
   year   percent
1: 2015   0.16
2: 2016   0.23
3: 2017   0.14
4: 2018   0.64
5: 2019   0.15
6: 2020   0.24
```

I have tried:

```
ggplot(data = mydata)+
geom_bar(aes(x = year, y = percent),position = 'fill', stat = 'identity')
```

Comment: You could show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Put fill in aes() and then use position = position_stack()

Comment: What values are stacked? At the x-axis value of `year = 2015`, you have a single `y` value `percent = 0.16`. A stacked bar chart needs 2 or more y values for a single x value, usually differentiated by a `fill` color mapping. All your years have a single y value, so there's nothing to stack. And if there were more y values, you'd still need a 3rd variable to distinguish between the things in the stack.

Comment: As mentioned above, "stacked" makes sense if you have several variables per x-axis value. However, looking at your code, the argument `position = 'fill'` doesn't make much sense here. Try something like this: `ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x=year)) + geom_col(aes(y=percent, fill = percent))`

Comment: @GregorThomas add your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggplot` will only plot data that's there. You want to include data that's implied, but not actually there, `(1 - percent)`. We'll create it explicitly, and then the plotting will go easily.

```
data %>%
  mutate(percent = 1 - percent, type = "not there") %>%
  bind_rows(data) %>%
  mutate(type = coalesce(type, "there")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = percent, fill = type)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

These days, `geom_col` is preferred to `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`, and it stacks by default.

Of course, change the labels and colors to whatever you want them to be.

---

Using this sample data

```
data = read.table(text = '   year   percent
1: 2015   0.16
2: 2016   0.23
3: 2017   0.14
4: 2018   0.64
5: 2019   0.15
6: 2020   0.24', header = T)
```